# gnuplot: plot sphere with solid color and some points on its surface

Tags: gnuplot

As the title suggests, I would like to have a solid-colored sphere (say e.g. red) with some dots on its surface (say black).
I managed to plot the sphere, color it, and plot the points. But then the points are not always on top of the sphere but rather get hidden behind the sphere although they are located outside of it:

```
set term wxt
set view equal xyz
set parametric
set urange [-pi/2:pi/2]
set vrange [0:2*pi] 
set isosamples 20,20
set palette model RGB functions 1,0,0
set pm3d depthorder

R=0.9

splot R*cos(u)*cos(v),R*cos(u)*sin(v),R*sin(u) w pm3d,\
"-" w p pt 7 pointsize 0.5 lc 0
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
e

pause -1
```

Note that even the

```
set pm3d depthorder
```

option from [GNUPLOT: Plotting on the surface of a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627187) does not help.

Comment: When I removed  `set pm3d depthorder` the points appeared with fedora gnuplot 5.0 patch1.

Comment: Related: [How to plot the surface of a sphere in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572292/how-to-plot-the-surface-of-a-sphere-in-gnuplot/)