# Plotting points on a sphere with gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, tikz

I have a data file with a set of points (x,y,z) that are restricted to the surface of a sphere.
I would like to plot them, but I wouldn't like all the points to appear on the plot,
only the ones visible in 3d.
My idea is to draw a solid sphere in order to hide the points from the back.
I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572292/how-to-plot-the-surface-of-a-sphere-in-gnuplot/) answer, but first, if I plot in pdf I get this.

[image]

Second, I would like to plot the points as dots with pt7 or something small, but in the gnuplot qt viewer
there is still a white wireframe, as seen:

[image]

I would like to achieve something similar to this:

[image]

How can I remove this wireframe? If someone knows a simpler way to do this with pgfplots, tikz or other software it would also suffice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could be the following:

1. Generate xyz-data for a prototype sphere with radius R
2. plot the sphere data with invisible lines (`lt -2`) and `set hidden3d`
3. plot your xyz points, here as demo `world.dat`.

Maybe I'm thinking to complicated and there are simpler solutions. I used an animated version to "illustrate" the hidden points. I hope you can adapt the code to your needs.

**Code:**

```
### points on sphere partly hidden
reset session
set view equal xyz
set xyplane relative 0
R = 1
unset tics
unset border

# sphere prototype data
set parametric
set isosamples 24
set samples 24
set urange [0:2*pi]
set vrange [-pi/2:pi/2]
set table $Sphere
    splot R*cos(u)*cos(v), R*sin(u)*cos(v), R*sin(v)
unset table
unset parametric

# convert "world.dat" data into x,y,z coordinates
# file can be found in directory gnuplot/demo
set angle degrees
set table $World
    plot "world.dat" u (R*cos($1)*cos($2)):(R*sin($1)*cos($2)):(R*sin($2)) w table
unset table

set hidden3d
set term gif animate size 400,400 delay 20 optimize
set output "tbWorldInDots.gif"

N = 36
do for [i=N:1:-1] {
    set view 90,360./N*i,1.8
    splot \
        $Sphere u 1:2:3 w l lt -2 notitle , \
        $World u 1:2:3 w p pt 7 ps 0.5 lc rgb "black" notitle, \
}
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I wasn't aware of `lt -2`, adding it to the sphere removed the wireframe from view.

Comment: well, I wasn't aware too. Unless I asked this question two days ago... https://stackoverflow.com/q/61684554/7295599  Apparently, `lt -2` is the equivalent of `lt nodraw`, however, I couldn't find neither of them in the newest manual.